# Redirecting display linux

Tags: linux, display, sh

from a sh shell, I am running a script calling a Software that requires opening a Gui. It ends up with a flashing window each time the call is run.

I tried to unset the DISPLAY environment variable but I get the error from the software "{Software}:cannot connect to X Server". And the Software call is not going through.

Is it possible to redirect the display to a display that do not display anything instead of just turning it off?

Or is it possible to keep the display variable and properties but turn off the animations on the screen for the time the program is running (with hopefully an escape key)?

Comment: are you able tu run xterm/xload during the same session ? any error message in /var/log/x.log (or the like /var/log/messages, dmesg ? ) ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. and sorry for late reply. I am a user on a remote machine. no issue with xterm. but normally also no write access other places than my home directory. What is this var/log folder for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to turn off display Animation for an application.
the only solution is quite complex:

1) install a fake Display,

2) Redirect to Display

an example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in). You will therefore need a superuser access.